# Make image map selectable with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dictionary

I have requirements to make a image map of seats in a amphitheatre selectable, much like a check box, with 3 states: selected, unselected, and disabled. I wish to know if there is a way to do this so that selected images would become serialised for database submission?

I have it working with just checkboxes, but I can not use them for the client (they like pretty things :p)

Answer (score 2):

Check out my jquery plugin [ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/). It does exactly this: allows you to identify areas of an image map that should be highlighted and can maintain state. There are a lot of options for rendering the highlights, including using a second image as the source for the highlighted areas, as well as for identifying areas that should be ignored or fixed in a certain state. In the USA map example on that link:

- Washington State is permanently selected & does not respond to
  mouseover events
- Oregon is permanently deselected & does not respond
  to mouseover events (this is just as if it was not part of the map -
  but options can be changed on the fly so there might be reasons to
  include areas in the map but turn them off).
- Alaska is unselectable
  (but does respond to mouseover events)

You can also assign options that determine how each area highlight should appear on a per-area basis.

The full documentation is on [github](https://github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster/wiki).

You only need a single alternate image if you use the "alternate image" option for the highlights, the plug-in draws the content from the same area of a 2nd image to create each highlight.

It works with any HTML image map as the data source.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the jquery UI buttons?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#icons

That probably should help and you don't have to recode anything.

Comment: can they be part of an image? (like an image map?)

Comment: uhm no, but as I see it an image map would be quite unusable for it, cause you would need another image for each possible combination of clicked and disabled seats.

My thought was you needed something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/kufi/frxqf/

Comment: I was thinking just add a class to the sections when clicked... that just then means that I need to serialize anything clicked with that class... I'll take a look at that link